# VS 2008 atlcom.h ClassesAllowedInStream not defined (cannot convert parameter)

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, atlcom

I am trying to build a project in VC++2008 and it is giving the following error:

```
error C2664: 'HRESULT ATL::CComVariant::ReadFromStream
(IStream *,VARTYPE,ATL::ClassesAllowedInStream,DWORD)' :
cannot convert parameter 3 from 'const int' to 'ATL::ClassesAllowedInStream'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\atlmfc\include\atlcom.h
6054
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

This is an error that stems from a bug in the VS2008 Service Pack 1 installation. I had the same problem.

A workaround for me was to reinstall VS 2008 (setup option "repair/clean new install") and then immediately install SP1.

The bug occurs if a Windows SDK is installed between the installation of VS2008 and SP1. In this case, the VS2008 SP1 installation updates the file `atlcom.h`, but fails to update its included file `atlcomcli.h` accordingly, thus `ClassesAllowedInStream` is undefined.

See the discussions [on MSDN Social](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ad698507-d62c-4e7b-bb7a-12a03b939594/atlcomh-classesallowedinstream-undefined?forum=vclanguage) and [in this mailing list](http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/visual-studio-2008-windows-7-help-120657691.html).