# cannot covert parameter from const int to atl classesallowedinstream

Tags: c++, constants

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot convert parameter 3 from const int to classesallowedinstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558278/cannot-convert-parameter-3-from-const-int-to-classesallowedinstream)

ReadFromStream(IStream *,VARTYPE,ATL::ClassesAllowedInStream,DWORD)' : **cannot convert parameter 3 from 'const int' to 'ATL::ClassesAllowedInStream'**

I am getting the above error message while building a project. Please anyone suggest a solution.

Thanks

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569938/convert-param-from-int-to-classesallowedinstream

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates you are trying to pass in a type that does not implicitly convert to `ClassesAllowedInStream` or is not derived from `ClassesAllowedInStream` .

I've not come across a `ClassesAllowedInStream` class is but I'd imagine it is a common base class for all streams that can be used in this function. Check the object you are passing into the function inherits from this base class.

Answer (score 0):

1) Stop asking duplicate questions.

2) The reason nobody has answered is because you're asking a poor question. It's tagged badly. We can't see your calling code. We don't know what you're trying to do. All we get is the error, which is telling you the same thing it's telling us: there's no constructor available to turn an `int` into an instance of `ATL::ClassesAllowedInStream`. Googling hasn't helped much as I'm not familiar with the ATL (namespace? class?).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee309358.aspx might help you out. It shows how a `ATL::ClassesAllowedInStream` is built.

In short, if you want our help, we need you to help us help you.